# Why is my MySQL query so slow?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

```
Background:
entities tables currently has 14,111 records
articles table currently has 5211 records
```

**I am trying to find all articles that are active (completed) and have the entity 'google'**

```
# Finding articles that have the entity google takes:
# 4 ms
SELECT `Article`.`id` FROM `articles_entities` AS `ArticlesEntity`
LEFT JOIN `entities` AS `Entity` ON (`ArticlesEntity`.`entity_id` = `Entity`.`id`)
WHERE `Entity`.`strict` = 'google'

# Finding articles that have the entity google and is active takes:
# 1800 ms
SELECT `Article`.`id` FROM `articles_entities` AS `ArticlesEntity` 
LEFT JOIN `entities` AS `Entity` ON (`ArticlesEntity`.`entity_id` = `Entity`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `articles` AS `Article` ON (`ArticlesEntity`.`article_id` = `Article`.`id`)
WHERE `Entity`.`strict` = 'google' AND `Article`.`state` = 'completed'
```

What might be the issue with the query taking so long?

*I would add that both fields in the pivot table are indexed.*

Thanks in advance for you help

***UPDATE***

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE Entity ref PRIMARY,strict strict 767 const 1 Using where
1 SIMPLE ArticlesEntity ref article_id,entity_id,article_id_2 entity_id 108 b2b.Entity.id 4  
1 SIMPLE Article eq_ref PRIMARY,state PRIMARY 108 b2b.ArticlesEntity.article_id 1 Using where
```

Comment: How many rows does the query return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity.strict or Article.state are not indexed.
Use EXPLAIN before your SELECT statement and check which tables are being fully scanned. That will hint what needs indexing.

Comment: What indexes do you have on each table, and what does EXPLAIN tell you?

Answer (score 1):

do you really need the left join?! imho your query should get a boost without it ;)